# What are the different ways of making a Joomla! website mobile friendly?

Tags: joomla, usability, mobile, user-friendly

I am involved in the development of a number of Joomla! websites and we would like to make these websites mobile friendly. I have done a bit of searching online and I can't seem to find any standard way of doing this. I have have come across a few Joomla! extensions that claim to make themselves mobile friendly for this device or that device. However, I am weary to just start trying these out.

Do any of you know of standard ways to make a Joomla! site mobile friendly?

Answer (score 1):

Since there are lots of ways to do this here are some common sense options:

1. Find a theme that only activates when a user accesses the site from a mobile browser.
2. Since Mobile Safari is a very popular browser, you will want to add relevant tags to allow resizing, set default orientation, etc. You can find out more information [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/navigation/).

Comment: Do you know of some sort of tutorial about making and/or setting up a Joomla! theme that is only for mobile?

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/twom/building-mobile-websites-with-joomla

You could also buy a theme: http://themeforest.net/item/joomla-mobile-dark-theme/16040

Comment: That slide show has some interesting stuff on it, but it should be noted that the software/plugins referenced on it are no longer around/supported.